# A shocking event

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

When I'm all over the place - give me a yelling
When I need hair washing - give me a frightening
When I need a clutch - give me soft singing
When I need an aromatic - give me a whole county
When I need a little taking - give me a carry
When I'm just getting started - give me a finger
When I want to get wetter - give me a place to hide
When I need contraceptives - give me a lot
When I need to fill up - give me a boost
When I need an explosive in mixture - give me after shot
When I need to word it sharply - give me a crazy one
When I need a firm hold - give me a lasting embrace

After I dropped drinking and Cheerios (too bad!), I heard of a shocking event.
Who am I, and what is it?

Hint:

> The event's aftershocks, ooh no!

Answer (score 6):

**Partial Answer**

I'm not sure about the shocking event but I think you are

> Amp

Each line indicates

> Wordplay the word defined in the second part surrounds **amp** to give the word defined in the first part.

When I'm all over the place - give me a yelling

> R**amp**ant - *to rant* is to speak or shout at length in an angry, impassioned way.

When I need hair washing - give me a frightening

> Sh**amp**oo - *shoo* is a word said to frighten or drive away a person or animal.

When I need a clutch - give me soft singing

> Cl**amp** - not sure about this one but the second part could refer to the singer [CL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CL_(singer))

When I need an aromatic - give me a whole county

> S**amp**hire - where a county is equivalent to a *shire*.

When I need a little taking - give me a carry

> S**amp**ling - a *sling* is a flexible strap or belt used in the form of a loop to support or raise a hanging weight.

When I'm just getting started - give me a finger

> R**amp**ing - *ramping* as in "ramping up".

When I want to get wetter - give me a place to hide

> D**amp**en

When I need contraceptives - give me a lot

> T**amp**on - the contraceptive definition doesn't match here, although *ton* indicates a lot and I think this might be what OP was going for.

When I need to fill up - give me a boost

> J**amp**ack - a very clever one, jampack means to crowd and jack is a synonym for boost.

When I need an explosive in mixture - give me after shot

> Fired**amp** - a combustible gas, *fired* may be the past tense of fire, synonym for shoot.

When I need to word it sharply - give me a crazy one

> L**amp**oon - a *loon* is a crazy or foolish person.

When I need a firm hold - give me a lasting embrace

> Cl**amp**ing

After I dropped drinking and Cheerios (too bad!), I heard of a shocking event.
Who am I, and what is it?

> Not sure about this part, I feel like there is some anagramming and wordplay with the words 'amp', 'cheerios' and possibly 'drinking'. The best I could come up with was KIM CHAPIRON RESIGNED although there are some interesting words in the subanagrams such as IMPEACHED, IMPRISONED and CHARGED which might also be involved.

Comment: County, not country. That might help.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks, completely misread it the whole time. Think I've got it now.

Comment: rot13(Gur pbagenprcgvirf bar vf G(NZC)BAF, lrf) - everything else is correct, so now you just need to figure out what you heard of.

Comment: Is the clutch-singing one correct? That seems a little redundant with one of the others.

Comment: @Avi tampons are not contraceptives.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, indeed - that was a bad clue